# Asp.Net Core MVC chart control namespace issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on asp.net core mvc web application and trying to add chart on page. I used the below code to display basic chart but it fails asking for a missing chart namespace. I tried with few namespaces but it didnt work. Where should I add namespace and what may be the exact namespace for make chart control work in asp.net core mvc application.

**Error:**

```
The type or namespace name 'Chart' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
```

My Code:

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

**Edit**

Based on comment I tried installing system.web.helpers dll. It did not work and showed the below warning

warning NU1701: Package 'System-Web-Helpers.dll 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Its in the `System.Web.Helpers` namespace

Comment: where can I find this dll, nuget package name or local location please. Currently I have asp.net core mvc application.

Comment: [System-Web-Helpers.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System-Web-Helpers.dll/)

Comment: I do not see that in references in my asp.net core mvc project. Any option to find that dll?

Comment: I gave the the nuget link in my previous comment!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I hope installing this package will not impact asp.net core mvc application.

Comment: I tried adding above nuget package  but still it is showing the same error. Any clue? I tried System.Web.Helpers.Chart to check if I can access Chart from it. But I am unable to find Chart in Helpers.

Comment: This chart you try to use is not valid for Core projects anymore. See e.g. https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/creating-charts-with-aspnet-core-LG